# Data leakage: Does it make sense to split time series this way?

Tags: time-series, train

I’m trying to make sense of how to create the training data for time series.
Let’s say we have sales data:

```
Day, sales
  1,    60
  2,    65
  3,    80
  4,    90
  5,   100
```

Then we create such training samples:

```
  x1=[60, 65]   y1=[ 80]
  x2=[65, 80]   y2=[ 90]
  x3=[80, 90]   y3=[100]
```

My worry is: If we train a model using such training samples, wouldn’t the model already “see” the `y1` as `x2` when we are feeding `x2` into the training process? Isn’t that some kind of data leakage?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you post your data in some sort of table, and explain some more about your partitions. What are the x's and what are the y's.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I have added some formatting ;)

Comment: Are you doing rolling cross validation for time series?

Comment: Not really specific to cross validation, so that’s a no. But question is directed towards a general training procedure for time series because for most other ml structured data I have dealt with, the y_t-1 is not in the x_1. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing then. Are these 3 different independent models? Why? What is your goal here? Nothing seems to be leaking here if that's the case.